# iPhone browser re-sizes form element placeholder font-size

Tags: iphone, html, forms, placeholder, font-size

The problem I am having IS NOT with text on my webpage, nevermind "is it inside a `<p>` tag, or make sure it's in a `<div>` and `-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;` or `100%;` does not fix this problem.

What I'm talking about is the `placeholder` values that display inside a text field are being re-sized by the iPhone browser and this is in turn re-sizing the height of each text field and in turn throwing off the alignment of the form fields to their backgrounds.

[Link to Problem (Visit with iphone to see the problem, obviously)](http://www.doitrightny.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was not the font size, but rather the input boxes themselves.
The iPhone browser was adding a padding to them, so this was the fix:

```
`input{padding:1px 0;}`
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your source, it looks like you may be trying to use

```
<input type="blah" placeholder="text">
```

but you do not affect the placeholder style in these kinds of tags.  Instead, you should use something like

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder { ...whatever here... }
```

to affect styling.

Check out [this link on styling placeholders in various browsers](http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder-css).

Comment: This does not really address my question, but I appreciate you passing on this info. Although, I notice that ueing `placeholder="..."` inside of `<input>` works on all browsers except for IE.